# OLEDB Connect not working consistently on Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp-classic, oledb

I'm tasked with getting a classic ASP page working in conjunction with some ASP.NET pages on our new server architecture. I've managed to get the classic ASP pages to work on my dev box (running Windows Server 2008 SP2, 64 bit), but when they're pushed to the server (or my co-worker's devbox) the page grinds to a halt at the Connect statement at the end of:

```
Const DB_CONN = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=joeblow;Password=connectme;Data Source=MyDB;Persist Security Info=False"

Dim mcnnsws
Set mcnnsws = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

mcnnsws.Connect DB_CONN
```

If I remove the above content and just put in a Response.Write("blah") it works fine on all machines, so I'm sure I have the ASP settings in IIS7.5 adequately set. I think it's a setting or how my db connection is set up because my code base on the server doesn't work, but the server's codebase on my machine does work.

I've tried to get the system to spit out an error message (debugging, IE settings, still just dies) and I've tried connecting to the DB instance using SQLPLUS (works fine).

Is there anyway to get the connection attempt to spit out more of an error? Or has anyone else encountered something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm whether, your SQL Server, ASP is running at the same bit architecture, i.e. whether they're all 64 bit. You can compare your ASP with a standalone VBS that has similar code and try it against both VBScript Windows Script Host (C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe and C:\Windows\SysWoW64\WScript.exe).

IIS can be configured to control whether your ASP are run 32 bit or 64 bit.